# Annotate queryset with __max lookup of related model

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 1.10.

I have a couple of models that looks like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...


class TransitionLog(models.Model):
    TransitionStates =[
        ('state_one', _('State One')),
        ('state_two', _('State Two')),
        ('state_three', _('State Three'))
    ]
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    transitioned_to = models.CharField(choices=TransitionStates, null=False, blank=False)
    transitioned_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And what I would like to do is annotate the `Product` QuerySet with the latest transition state, which is the `transitioned_to` field of `TransitionLog`. The latest state would be the one with the most recent `transitioned_timestamp`.

I've gotten most of the way there by doing the following:

```
Product.objects.annotate(latest_transition=Case(When(transitionlog__pk=Max('transitionlog__pk'), then='transitionlog__transitioned_to')))
```

However my concern there is that `Max()` only looks at the pk and takes the highest one, which would work for my purposes but what I would rather do is get the latest `transitioned_timestamp`.

The problem is I'm not sure how to do a match on the `TransitionLog.pk` after I find the latest timestamp. I know I could also do this in two queries by getting the log separately and doing the join from there, but I'd like to avoid that as well.

Could anyone suggest a way that I could get the most recent by timestamp transition log for a given `Product` in a single query? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I can think of is to look the other way round, getting the latest transitions for each product. Then, you'd have your products accessing them by their transitions.

```
transitions = TransitionLog.objects.all().order_by('-transitioned_timestamp').distinct('product_id')
```

One thing might be a problem, though. You won't have products that have no associated `TrasitionLog` objects.